# Google Cloud Translate 400 Invalid resource name location even though it is valid

Tags: python, google-api, google-colaboratory, google-translate, invalid-argument

Running on google colab.
I have basically copied the code from [googles tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples/translate-v3-batch-translate-text#translate_v3_batch_translate_text-python) yet the code has returned multiple errors (most of which have been solved by reinstalling packages).

I have my environment authentication variables correctly setup.

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     72         try:
---> 73             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     74         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

7 frames
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Invalid resource name location. Identifier must contain only lowercase letters, digits, or hyphens.;  Resource type: location"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1616934732.016610183","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.65.74:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1061,"grpc_message":"Invalid resource name location. Identifier must contain only lowercase letters, digits, or hyphens.;  Resource type: location","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InvalidArgument                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid resource name location. Identifier must contain only lowercase letters, digits, or hyphens.;  Resource type: location
```

This is my code:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud
from google.cloud import translate


def batch_translate_text(
    input_uri="gs://HIDDEN/HIDDEN.txt",
    output_uri="gs://HIDDEN/out",
    project_id="HIDDEN",
    timeout=180,
):
    """Translates a batch of texts on GCS and stores the result in a GCS location."""
    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "eu (multiple regions in European Union)"
    # Supported file types: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    gcs_source = {"input_uri": input_uri}

    input_configs_element = {
        "gcs_source": gcs_source,
        "mime_type": "text/plain",  # Can be "text/plain" or "text/html".
    }
    gcs_destination = {"output_uri_prefix": output_uri}
    output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination}
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/language
    operation = client.batch_translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "source_language_code": "sv",
            "target_language_codes": ["en"],  # Up to 10 language codes here.
            "input_configs": [input_configs_element],
            "output_config": output_config
        }
    )

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result(timeout)

    print("Total Characters: {}".format(response.total_characters))
    print("Translated Characters: {}".format(response.translated_characters))

batch_translate_text()
```

This should be correct according to [the API](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/2.0.2/gapic/v3beta1/api.html) and the identifiers only contains lowercase letters, digits, or hyphens.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same error, in my case it is resolved by changing the value of the location with **us-central1**.

```
location = "us-central1"
```